# using tikz to draw a graph with curved paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have tried but cannot produce curved paths instead ended up with a straight one. I have tried using controls but it also produces a straight path. Cannot understand why?
[image: cross flow and parallel flow HE]

```
    \documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \subfigure[Parallel flow]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}}}]
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (4,0) -- (4,4);
        
  \draw[postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.5}{stealth},
    ](0,1) node[left] {$T_{c,i}$} to [in=180,out=20] node[right, pos=1]{$T_{c,o}$} (4,1.5);
        
        \draw [postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.5}{stealth},
    ](0,3) node[left] {$T_{h,i}$} to [in=-180,out=-20] node[right, pos=1] {$T_{h,o}$}(4,2.5);
        \draw [line width=1.25pt,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror},xshift=0.8cm,yshift=0pt] (4,1.5) -- (4,2.5) node [black,midway,xshift=0.6cm]{$\Delta T_2$};
        \draw [line width=1.25pt,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=5pt},xshift=-0.8cm,yshift=0pt] (0,1) -- (0,3) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm]{$\Delta T_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }\label{he-parallel-flow}
    \subfigure[Cross flow]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with #2}}]
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (4,0) -- (4,4);
        \draw [postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.5}{\arrowreversed{stealth}},
    ] (0,2) node[left]{$T_{c,o}$} to [in=-180,out=-30] node[right, pos=1]{$T_{c,i}$} (4,1);
        \draw [postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.5}{\arrow{stealth}},
    ] (0,3) node[left]{$T_{h,i}$} to [in=-180,out=-30] node[right, pos=1]{$T_{h,o}$}(4,2);
        \draw [line width=1.25pt,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=3pt},xshift=-0.8cm,yshift=0pt] (0,2) -- (0,3) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm]{$\Delta T_1$};
        \draw [line width=1.25pt,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror},xshift=0.8cm,yshift=0pt] (4,1) -- (4,2) node [black,midway,xshift=0.6cm]{$\Delta T_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }\label{he-cross-flow}
    \caption{Heat Exchanger mechanism}
    \label{heat-ex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're only using `--` which are straight lines (unless decorations change them). Can you show how you used `.. controls` or, say, `to[out=-30. in=180]`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel solved using [in=180,out=20]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my approach using `controls` :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\tikzstyle{brace}=[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=5pt}]
\tikzstyle{arrowstyle}=[scale=1] 
\tikzstyle{directed}=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with{\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, line width=0.5mm]
%The axis :
\draw[->] (0,-0.5)--(0,6); 
\draw[->] (-0.5,0)--(6,0); 

%Marking initial temperatures : 
\filldraw (0,5)circle(0.025) node[left] {$T_{h,i}$};
\filldraw (0,2)circle(0.025) node[left] {$T_{c,i}$};

%The bezier's curves corresponding to variations of temperature :
\draw[line width=0.2mm, directed] (0,5)..controls(1,4.5) and (2.5,3.95)..(5,4); 
\draw[line width=0.2mm, directed] (0,2) ..controls(1,2.5) and (2.5,2.95) .. (5,3); 

%Marking final temperatures : 
\filldraw (5,4)circle(0.025) node[right] {$T_{h_0}$};
\filldraw (5,3)circle(0.025) node[right] {$T_{c_0}$};
\draw[dashed, line width=0.1mm] (5,0)--(5,5);

%The braces : 
\draw[brace] (-0.75,2)--(-0.75,5) node[left=0.4, midway] {$\Delta T_1$};
\draw[brace] (5.75,4)--(5.75,3) node[right=0.4, midway] {$\Delta T_2$};

%The title : 
\node[scale=1.5] at (2.5,-1.5) {\strut The parallel flow};

%Let's shift the origin ;) 
\begin{scope}[shift={(12,0)}]
%The axis :
\draw[->] (0,-0.5)--(0,6); 
\draw[->] (-0.5,0)--(6,0); 

%Marking initial temperatures : 
\filldraw (0,5)circle(0.025) node[left] {$T_{h,i}$};
\filldraw (0,3)circle(0.025) node[left] {$T_{c,0}$};

%The bezier's curves corresponding to variations of temperature :
\draw[line width=0.2mm, directed] (0,5) ..controls (1.5,4) and (3,3.5).. (5,3.5);
\draw[line width=0.2mm, directed] (0,3) ..controls (1.5,2) and (3,1.5).. (5,1.5);

%Marking final temperatures : 
\filldraw (5,3.5)circle(0.025) node[right] {$T_{h_0}$};
\filldraw (5,1.5)circle(0.025) node[right] {$T_{c_i}$};
\draw[dashed, line width=0.1mm] (5,0)--(5,5);

%The braces : 
\draw[brace] (-0.75,3)--(-0.75,5) node[left=0.4, midway] {$\Delta T_1$};
\draw[brace] (5.75,3.5)--(5.75,1.5) node[right=0.4, midway] {$\Delta T_2$};

%The title : 
\node[scale=1.5] at (2.5,-1.5) {\strut Cross flow};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I love your code by the way, it's just need some optimisation. I Hope you liked this approach. Have a nice day !